# What s the bb/100 from BigBlind from a NL25 online reg?

Tags: nlhe, statistics, blinds

I m watching my bb/100 NLHE stats sorted by position at the moment . 
The bb/100 is positiv from every Position , only BigBlind is -22.7bb/100.
I think it s normal that I have a negative bb/100 from BigBlind , but I m not sure, what the normal value or the value of a reg is . 
All stats are from 400k NL25 hands played at PS . 
Whats your bb/100 from BigBlind and what bb/100 you think is normal for a reg . 
Thank you for your help.